# <Ruby on Rails> Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm a beginner in ruby on rails and was following an online tutorial. I got lost immediately on routes. Every time I try to go to my url 'pages/help' an error is displaying in the browser  "**The action 'show' could not be found for PagesController**". I have a ruby partitions named _header that contains these codes:

```
<header>
    <%= link_to logo, root_path %>


    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active">
        <%= link_to "Home |", root_path %>
      </li>

      <li><%= link_to "Help |", pages_help_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Sign In", '#'%></li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

And when I try to click the "Help" link the error occurs.

My routes.rb contains just these codes:

```
BakeShop::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :pages
  root :to => 'pages#home'

  #match '/help', :to => 'pages#help'
  get "pages/help"
end
```

and i have a PagesController with only these codes:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home

  end

  def help

  end
end
```

and when I run 'rake routes' the lists contained are:

```
     pages GET    /pages(.:format)          pages#index
           POST   /pages(.:format)          pages#create
  new_page GET    /pages/new(.:format)      pages#new
 edit_page GET    /pages/:id/edit(.:format) pages#edit
      page GET    /pages/:id(.:format)      pages#show
           PATCH  /pages/:id(.:format)      pages#update
           PUT    /pages/:id(.:format)      pages#update
           DELETE /pages/:id(.:format)      pages#destroy
      root GET    /                         pages#home
pages_help GET    /pages/help(.:format)     pages#help
```

And I certainly have home.html.erb and help.html.erb created in my views folder. And the twist is that when I create a 'show.html.erb' in my views folder and create an action in my pages controller named 'show', the error disappears and links to .

So what I'm saying is, can anyone explain this? Why is rails looking for 'show' action, and not 'help' action, that I didn't define

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to understand about routes in Rails is that the order of routes specified is very important.  In your `config/routes.rb` file you have routes specified in the following order:

```
resources :pages
root :to => 'pages#home'
get "pages/help"
```

So, what this does is, matches the routes defined with `resources :pages` first.  As you can see in the output of `rake routes`, Rails generated the following routes for that specific line i.e. `resources :pages`:

```
     pages GET    /pages(.:format)          pages#index
           POST   /pages(.:format)          pages#create
  new_page GET    /pages/new(.:format)      pages#new
 edit_page GET    /pages/:id/edit(.:format) pages#edit
      page GET    /pages/:id(.:format)      pages#show
           PATCH  /pages/:id(.:format)      pages#update
           PUT    /pages/:id(.:format)      pages#update
           DELETE /pages/:id(.:format)      pages#destroy
```

Also note that `pages_help GET    /pages/help(.:format)     pages#help` is at the bottom of that list.  So what is happening is when you navigate to `/pages/help`, Rails finds the first `GET` request that matches that pattern, in this case:

```
page GET    /pages/:id(.:format)      pages#show
```

And since you don't have the `show` action defined, it's throwing that error "The action 'show' could not be found for PagesController".

So, to solve you specific problem without the `show` action and `show.html.erb`, you can rearrange the `config/routes.rb` as follows:

```
BakeShop::Application.routes.draw do
  get "pages/help" # Move this line before resources :pages
  resources :pages
  root :to => 'pages#home'
end
```

Moving `get "pages/help"` will ensure that for your url `/pages/help` this route will match and your `help.html.erb` will be rendered.

**Update:**

How it matched `pages/show`?

```
# In the comments below where .format is used think of various extensions just as html, js, json, xml etc but not required.

pages GET    /pages(.:format)          pages#index
# Matches /pages, /pages.format

new_page GET    /pages/new(.:format)      pages#new
# Matches /pages/new, /pages/new.format

edit_page GET    /pages/:id/edit(.:format) pages#edit
# Matches /pages/1/edit, /pages/1/edit.format or pages/anything/edit.format.  Note that the edit in the end is required here,the only variable here is id and format

page GET    /pages/:id(.:format)      pages#show
# Matches /pages/1, /pages/anything, /pages/1.format, /pages/anything.format.  In the question /pages/help matches.
```

Comment: I love it! Great answer and explanation. If you don't mind me asking an additional question, what's this GET pattern that rails is passing?  because when you said "Rails finds the first GET request", aren't the pages_path, new_page_path and edit_page_path are all GET requests? Why didn't rails match them instead?

Comment: @Mr.Slow, Glad you liked my answer.  I've added some update to it for your comment, please have a look at it and comment if I was not clear.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the default root in your routes.rb.

Update routes.rb:-

```
BakeShop::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :pages
  root :to => 'pages#home'

  #match '/help', :to => 'pages#help'
  get "pages/help" #this is not required
match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the route for the show action (page_path) and the route for your pages_help_path conflict. If you simply move the line `get "pages/help"` before the line `resources :pages` it will work as you intend.

Routes.rb:

```
BakeShop::Application.routes.draw do
  get "pages/help"
  resources :pages
  root :to => 'pages#home'
end
```